Angular @ngrx/signals SignalStore not working when used inside a library in workspace
when using the signal store inside a library and use a nested object we have this errror:
projects/ltelib/ui-sdk/dashboard/layout/src/store/layout-settings.store.ts:13:14 - error TS2742: The inferred type of 'LayoutSettingsStore' cannot be named without a reference to '../../../../../../../node_modules/@ngrx/signals/src/deep-signal'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
import { signalStore, withState } from '@ngrx/signals';

type BooksState = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  filter: { query: string; order: 'asc' | 'desc' };
};

const initialState: BooksState = {
  isLoading: false,
  filter: { query: '', order: 'asc' },
};

export const LayoutSettingsStore = signalStore(
  withState<BooksState>(initialState)
);

this is not my final code, i used to test and its not working.
If i use the same code but in an app it works peerfectly, but i want to implement in a library.
